# Pagination not working on JQGrid

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, pagination

I am trying to do pagination in my jqgrid.
Here is my code:

```
<div>
    <table id="JQGridDemo"></table>
    <div id="jqFooter" style="text-align:center;"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#JQGridDemo').jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("JQGrid")',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "post",
        colNames: ['ID', 'Name', 'Model', 'Cost', 'Date'],
        colModel: [{
            name: 'ID',
            index: 'ID'
        }, {
            name: 'Name',
            index: 'Name'
        }, {
            name: 'Model',
            index: 'Model'
        }, {
            name: 'Cost',
            index: 'Cost'
        }, {
            name: 'Date',
            width: '464px',
            index: 'Date'
        }],
        height: '100%',
        autowidth: true,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        pager: "#jqFooter",
        rowNum: 10,
        sortName: 'Name',
        viewRecords: true,
        sortorder: "asc",
        loadonce: true,
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            cell: "cell",
            id: "ID",
            userdata: "userdata"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

and my controller code is

```
public JsonResult JQGrid() {
     AssignmentEntities entities = new AssignmentEntities();
     var gridDetail = (from list in entities.Brands select list).ToList();
     var jsonData = new {
         total = 6, page = page, records = gridDetail.Count, rows = gridDetail
     };
     return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Can anyone tell me why pagination is not working for me??

Comment: I don't see any clear error in the code. One can improve it, but the pagination should work. What you exactly mean under "pagination is not working"? How many items your returns? Is it more as 10 (see `rowNum`)? Are "Page Next" (">") button in the pager enabled? Do you have any error message it you click it?

Comment: I have six records..I changed rownum as 5. first 5 records are displaying in page 1..when i click page next button its not going to next page.

Comment: shall u tell my controller code is correct or not (  var jsonData = new {
         total = 6, page = page, records = gridDetail.Count, rows = gridDetail)

Comment: If you use `loadonce: true` then `total`, `page` and `records` will be **ignored**. You can use just `return Json((from list in entities.Brands select list).ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` directly. If you append your question with JSON response returned from the server one could reproduce the problem which you describe. You can get exact server response using [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/get-fiddler) or Developer Tools if IE (press F12 to start).

Comment: yes u r correct..i added loadonce:true..now its working.

Comment: The code which you posted originally contained already `loadonce: true` option. It was the reason why I could not understand the problem which you described. In any way it's good that all works now.

Answer (score 1):

Iam using JqGrid which is working fine for me, hope it helps you in finding the issue

- Make Sure Jquery Neccessary files are loaded
- Make Sure Grid.locale file is loaded
- if you are still unable to get paging debug in Google Chrome See the Console Tab u ll find the error if in case u missed out anything

  `

  ```
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
              url: '/EmployeeWiseReport/GetGridData/',
              datatype: 'json',
              mtype: 'GET',
              width: 600,
              colNames: ['Employee Id', 'UserName', 'MobileNo', 'EmailId', 'NOofChild', 'ChildName'],
              colModel: [
                { name: 'UserId', index: 'UserId', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'UserName', index: 'UserName', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'MobileNo', index: 'MobileNo', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'EmailId', index: 'EmailId', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'NOofChild', index: 'NOofChild', align: 'left' },
                { name: 'ChildName', index: 'ChildName', align: 'left' }
  ```

  ```
          ],
          jsonReader: {
              repeatitems: false,
              root: function(obj) { return obj; },
              page: function(obj) { return 1; },
              total: function(obj) { return 1; },
              records: function(obj) { return obj.length; }
          },
          loadonce: true,
          pager: jQuery('#pager'),
          rowNum: 10,
          rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
          sortname: 'UserId',
          sortorder: "asc",
          viewrecords: false,
          caption: 'Employee Wise Report Information'
      }).navGrid(pager, { edit: false, add: false, del: false, refresh: true, search: false });
  });
  ```

  ```
    <table id="list" class="scroll" style="height: 250px; width: 550px;" cellpadding="0"
  cellspacing="0" width="80%">
  ```

  ```
   <table id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align: center;">
   </table>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at Gowtham answer I could understand what I was doing wrong.
I'm working with a kind of return that json object is inside of variable. I hope this can clarify for other users.

My JSON: [status: 'ok', obj: {currpage: 1, totalpages: 3, totalrecords: 30, rows: {...}}]

```
jsonReader: {
                page: "obj.currpage",
                total: "obj.totalpages",
                records: "obj.totalrecords",
                repeatitems: false,
                root: "obj.rows",
                cell: "cell",
                id: "0"
            },
```